# std::localtime one second leads to 30 mins gap

Tags: c++, localtime

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    std::time_t t = 893665799;
    std::tm * tm = std::localtime(&t);
    printf("local time duration =>year:%d, month:%d, day:%d, hour:%d, min:%d, sec:%d\n",tm->tm_year, tm->tm_mon, tm->tm_mday, tm->tm_hour, tm->tm_min, tm->tm_sec);

    t = 893665800;
    tm = std::localtime(&t);
    printf("local time duration =>year:%d, month:%d, day:%d, hour:%d, min:%d, sec:%d\n",tm->tm_year, tm->tm_mon, tm->tm_mday, tm->tm_hour, tm->tm_min, tm->tm_sec);
}
```

893665799 is a magic utc.

When u change ur timezone to **Pitcairn Islands**.

The log shows below

local time duration =>year:98, month:3, day:26, hour:23, min:59, sec:59

local time duration =>year:98, month:3, day:27, hour:0, min:30, sec:0

what's going on ? why 1 sec leads to 30 mins gap??

Comment: have u changed ur timezone to Pitcairn Islands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the `time_t` given is exactly one second prior to rolling into a new hour, it's almost certainly to do with daylight savings time or some other adjustment.

And, with a bit of Google-fu, [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/pitcairn/adamstown?year=1998) it is:

> **27 Apr 1998 - Time Zone Change (PNT → PST)**
>
> When local standard time was about to reach Monday, 27 April 1998, 12:00:00, midnight clocks were turned forward 0:30 hours to Monday, 27 April 1998, 12:30:00 am local standard time instead.

This actually happens quite often, with various countries around the world moving their local times willy-nilly all over the place :-)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by another answer, local times change around all the time, what with the daylight savings and whatnots.

To "portably" represent one instant in time became almost impossible and so UTC is invented, which is a magical timezone* that is the standard way to represent time, only taking into account leap seconds.

To correctly handle all these cases is incredibly tedious, but thankfully Howard Hinnant has [this amazing library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) that does everything for you :)

<sub>* UTC is not really a timezone</sub>